# Angular Scope in javascript function with Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I use Typescript with Angular and Breezejs.

```
class CounterController {
    count: number = 0;
    static $inject = ['$scope'];


    constructor($scope) {
        $scope.vm = this;
    }

    setCount14(): void {  
        this.count = 14; // works
    }

    getQuestions(): void {
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/dbentities');
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Corporations").where("Name", "startsWith", "Zen");
        manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            this.count= 1; // works not!
        }
    }
}
```

How can i access the `count` property in the `querySucceeded` function correct?

Edit: better: there must be a way to pass a typescript function to `executeQuery(query).then` ?

Solution: [Pass Typescript function as a Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853644/pass-typescript-function-as-a-javascript-function/17853685?noredirect=1#comment26064269_17853685)

Then calling the `scope.$apply()` does apply the bindings.

Comment: Looks like a scoping issue, what is 'this' inside your 'querySucceeded' function?

Comment: I am not sure but it is a big object. Maybe the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `(data) => { this.count = 1; }` instead. or your "this" won't have the correct scope. OR as an alternative:

```
var me = this;
function querySucceeded(data) {
  me.count= 1; // works not!
}
```

e.g:

```
getQuestions(): void {
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/dbentities');
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Corporations").where("Name", "startsWith", "Zen");
    manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then((data) => { this.count= 1; });
}
```

Comment: both examples strangely work only when called the second time.

Comment: there must be a way to pass a typescript function to `executeQuery(query).then` ?

Comment: well it doesn't matter what function you pass in, this will always be bound incorrectly in so many situations in JavaScript (almost always to the caller)...

The () => {} in typescript really just does the "var me = this" trick for you... Why it doesn't work until the second time might indeed be odd, however are you running into a situation where you are exiting the Angular "scope" so to speak, and need to remember to do $scope.apply around your function?

Comment: passing the script function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853644/pass-typescript-function-as-a-javascript-function/17853685?noredirect=1#comment26064269_17853685

Comment: now I added a `thescope` property to my class which i set in the constructor to `$scope`. I then call `this.thescope.$apply()`in `myFunc` this works. I wonder if it is possible without the `$apply()`

Comment: Since I don't know where the callback originates from, this is difficult to say. The thing is that if data or callbacks originates from outside angular, then apply is needed, what apply does is that it starts a digest phase ones the function passed to apply completes, the digest phase is what runs the dirty checking of your models and updates the UI if changes happens. This is not needed when your calls originates from within angular... think of on-click vs ng-click... in the later ng click can it self wrap the callback inside an apply, same goes for when you use ng-resource or $http