# Pass Typescript function as a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, breeze

I use typescript with breeze. How can i pass a typescript function to `executeQuery.then`?

```
class MyClass{
 ...
    myFunc(data:any):void{
       ...
    }

    doQuery():void{
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/breeze/dbentities');
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Corporations").where("Name", "startsWith", "Zen");
        manager.executeQuery(query)
               .then(this.myFunc);  // does not work!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use `this.myFunc` instead of `myFunc`.</strike>

It might be a context problem. Try `this.myFunc.bind(this)` instead of `this.myFunc`.

---

For more information about *context*, refer ["this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fthis) and ["Function.prototype.bind"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind) article from MDN.

Comment: sorry forgotten to add this. But with `this` the function is also not called.

Comment: Then it might be context problem, try `this.myFunc.bind(this)`.

Comment: where should i call the binding?

Comment: It binds function's execution context(a.k.a `this`) to `this`. I updated my answer, please see linked articles. These are definitely better than my poor explanation. Also note that it has no concern with TypeScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, this is working perfectly in my own classes. What is "not working", what error message is thrown?

Second, to be sure that "this" is my typescript class context I always use a lambda like this:

```
doQuery(): void {
    ...
    manager.executeQuery(query).then((data: breeze.QueryResult) => {
        this.myFunc(data);
    });
}
```

In this case the TS compiler produces a "var _this = this" at the beginning of the doQuery function which is your class context and converts the "this.myFunc(data)" call to "_this.myFunc(data)".

And better use type declarations like "breeze.QueryResult" instead of any.